# c++ calculating elapsed seconds from 2 time moments

Tags: c++, time

I am trying to calculate how much seconds has been passed from 2 time moments. My code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;


int main()
{
    int FH, FM, FS, SH, SM, SS;

    cin >> FH >> FM >> FS >> SH >> SM >> SS;

    tm t1,t2;

    t1.tm_hour = FH;
    t1.tm_min = FM;
    t1.tm_sec = FS;
    t1.tm_mon = 1;
    t1.tm_mday = 1;


    t2.tm_hour = SH;
    t2.tm_min = SM;
    t2.tm_sec = SS;
    t2.tm_mon = 1;
    t2.tm_mday = 1;

    cout << difftime(mktime(&t2),mktime(&t1));
}
```

But it just keeps throwing 0.
Input is as follows:

```
FH, FM, FS -> First moment hours,minutes,seconds
SH, SM, SS -> Second moments hours, minutes, seconds
```

Comment: what is the input and expected output?

Comment: Example output - 1 1 1 2 2 2
Expected output - 3661

Basically, just elapsed seconds

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> tm t1,t2;
> ```

This leaves the two `tm` structures uninitialized, and the following code does not set all fields, so some of them may be left to invalid values.

Default initializing the two variables produces the [expected result](https://godbolt.org/z/f8Pb9s).

> ```
> tm t1 = {}, t2 = {};
> ```

This (and other) problem(s) can be caught by checking the return values of `mktime` against `-1` which [indicates failure](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/mktime).

Answer (score 1):

Going through the C API is error prone as it involves the local time zone.  If the date you happen to arbitrarily select in `tm` happens to be on a daylight saving boundary in your local time zone, your computation could be wrong by the change in offset.  This is because `mktime` converts a local time to UTC prior to using `difftime` to find the difference.

To avoid this pitfall, you can use the C++ `<chrono>` library:

```
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>

int
main()
{
    using namespace std;
    using namespace std::chrono;

    int FH, FM, FS, SH, SM, SS;

    cin >> FH >> FM >> FS >> SH >> SM >> SS;

    cout << (hours{SH} + minutes{SM} + seconds{SS} -
            (hours{FH} + minutes{FM} + seconds{FS})).count() << '\n';
}
```

There are no timezones involved in the above computation.